# Execute Function Before A Link onClick Event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am performing DOM manipulation on a page where I don’t have access to the source code.  I would simply like to prevent a link’s onClick handler from executing, add my own unrelated function then allow the original onClick function to execute as normal.  Here is an example of the page code:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myAjaxFunction('param1, param2');return false;" name="buyLink" id="buyLink" >Buy Now</a>
```

I have come up with the code framework below:

```
jQuery('#buyLink').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    my2ndFunction(); // alert(‘I ran’);
    //execute myAjaxFunction() here
});
```

I have two challenges:

1) When I use the Alert() code to test this out, the alert appears but the original function runs anyway (preventDefualt doesn’t seem to be working).

2) How do I call the original function complete with the correct dynamic parameter values? (maybe using “self” in some way?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, back up the original `onclick` handler.  Then, remove it from the element.  Finally, create your own handler.  In your handler, call the original function.

```
var orig_onclick = $('#buyLink').prop('onclick');
$('#buyLink').removeProp('onclick');

$('#buyLink').click(function(e){
    // Do your own code
    my2ndFunction();

    // Call the original function, with the correct context.
    return orig_onclick.call(this, e.originalEvent);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/qbz7wn9o/

Comment: That worked when I applied to my environment, but I couldn't get the jsfiddle to do anything.  Is the console output supposed to appear on the page or in my FireBug console (neither occurred)?

Comment: It's supposed to appear in the browser's console.  I don't use Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to achieve this without storing the onclick event.

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");

// add your listener
button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  alert("listener action");
  // calling stopImmediatePropagation here will prevent the inline action...
  // ...from executing once it's moved to afterwards in the queue
  //event.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

// move the inline listener to execute after yours
if (button.onclick !== null) {
  button.addEventListener("click", button.onclick);
  button.onclick = null;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="alert('inline action');">click me</button>
```